# How do I define a list of strings and replace each instance of the string in files in a subdirectory?

Tags: bash

#### input

Say I have three files in subdirectory /directory/: *a.txt*, *b.txt*, and *c.txt*.

```
a.txt
var1=bla
var2=blabla
var3=blablabla

b.txt
foo1=bar
foo2=barbar
foo3=barbarbar

c.txt
name1=string
name2=string2
name3=string3
```

I have created a 4th file, *variables.txt*

```
variables.txt
var2=new
foo1=newnew
foo3=newnewnew
```

#### desired output

I would like a **bash script** that uses the content of *variables.txt* to edit all files in /directory/, replacing any files with matching variables from variables.txt. For example, *a.txt*, *b.txt*, and *c.txt* become the following:

```
a.txt
var1=bla
var2=new
var3=blablabla

b.txt
foo1=newnew
foo2=barbar
foo3=newnewnew

c.txt
name1=string
name2=string2
name3=string3
```

*c.txt* does not change as nothing in variable.txt matches its variables.

How would this script look like?

#### context

In reality, I have about 20 files with 5-20 variables each, and I need to change maybe 3-4 variables in each file. Other users will also use variables.txt, defining it to suit their purposes, so the cleaner I can write variables.txt, the better. Fortunately, each variable has a unique name and only appears once in a file from this subdirectory. Thank you!

Comment: @oguzismail thanks for the reply. I'd gladly try more on my own, but the problem is I am not sure how to even begin. For example, building a sed query: I can do something like while read variables.txt; do sed -i ..., but I need the loop to read two strings: one string that defines the pattern I will search for, and the second string to define what I will replace the pattern with. I am not sure how to construct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk and the `inplace` extension:

```
awk -F= --include inplace '
  NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
  ($1 in a){$2=a[$1]}
  1' variable.txt /directory/[abc].txt
```

This script fills the array `a` with the content of file `variable.txt`.

For each other file, it replaces the value if the parameter is part of the array.

The `--include inplace` option allows to change files directly (without creating temporary file), which is the same as the `sed` `-i` option.

Comment: This works, thank you! I had to workaround the --include inplace as my Linux distribution is centos 7, which seems to not support awk 4.1. My final code was (sorry don't know how to do code markdown in comments):  ````for i in /directory/*.txt; do awk -F= ' BEGIN{OFS="=";}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){$2=a[$1]} 1' variables.txt $i > tmp && mv tmp $i done `````

Comment: Correction: ($1 in a && $1>0) Otherwise it adds OFS to empty lines since it also stores empty lines from variables.txt in the array.